# Wireless and Wired network - Different IP causing print issues

Tags: wireless-networking, dhcp

I am having some issues ( I believe) with DHCP on wired and wireless.

My Frontier router is setup with DHCP range: 192.168.254.10 - 254.

that seems to be fine and I see wired devices in the IP table with corresponding IP addresses assigned.

My wireless devices (phone, tablet, TV, printer) is getting 192.168.86.x

My challenge is configuring my new printer so it can print from both wired devices and wireless devices.

I am assuming because of the different subnets, that is not possible.  Is the solution as simple as changing the DHCP start address to 192.168.86.x??  I cannot see where or how to change the DHCP for wireless addresses.

But then as I am digging through the settings in the router, I see *generally* my wired devices are 192.168.254.x and wireless devices are 192.168.86.x  BUT, the Roomba is showing up in the IP table as having a 192.168.254.x addres; and it's definitely NOT a wired device, lol.

the printer is a brand new HP laserjet, PC's are running Windows 10.  wireless devices are android and apple.

Comment: further confusing the issue is, the router admin address is 192.168.254.254; my chromebook is reporting a 192.168.86.x address and can navigate to the Router Admin page; which is confusing to me why the printer (192.168.86.x) cannot be seen from my computer (192.168.254.x)

Comment: You may need the ISP to help you with / reset the router. Connect a device to a router admin page should give the correct address.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have one device as your router (modem/router).

Assuming so, make sure Wireless Isolation has been disabled so everything is on one subnet.

(In my own wireless router, wireless isolation is a part of each wireless profile).

Your ISP (Frontier Support) may need to help you disable Wireless Isolation.

You may need to reset the router to factory specifications and set it up again if some changes have made it difficult to navigate.

For this small network, one single subnet is the most desirable way to operate.

Comment: Thank you John - Total Control Wireless was turned on; I disabled it, made sure Wireless Isolation was not enabled,  rebooted the router and still appears to be two subnets.   Looks like I will need to get Frontier Support involved; oh the joy!   Thank you

Comment: Yes (about Support). You do not need two subnets in a tiny network.